# jQuery to hide form depending on select field?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, flask

I have an HTML form with multiple select fields... I want to display/hide a div based on a user's selection of a previous field.
Specifically, if a user selects "Before" or "After" on the select field, I want to hide the #Length-div... the odd thing is that I have already gotten this to work for the #Yes div, and I don't know what the difference is between these two.

```
        <div class="required">
            <label class="control-label" for="before_after">When?</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="before_after" name="before_after" required="">
                <option selected="" value="Until the prayer after">Until the prayer after</option>
                <option value="Before">Before</option>
                <option value="After">After</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group  required">
            <label class="control-label" for="recurring">Recurring</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="recurring" name="recurring" required="">
                <option selected="" value="No">No</option>
                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div name="Length-div" id="Length-div" style="display:none;">
            {{ wtf.form_field(form.length)}}
        </div>

        <div name="Yes" id="Yes" style="display: none;">
            {{ wtf.form_field(form.frequency)}}
            {{ wtf.form_field(form.end)}}
        </div>
```

My Jquery scripts:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#recurring").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
            if(optionValue=="No"){
                $("#Yes").hide()
            } else{
                $("#Yes").show();
            }
        }).change();
    $("#before_after").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue2 = $(this).attr("value");
            if(optionValue2=="Until the prayer after"){
                $("#Length-div").show();
            } else{
                $("#Length-div").hide();
            }
            
        }).change();
    });
});

});
</script>
```

Could you please let me know why my code works for the #Yes div but not for the #Length-div ? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Because your code structure is not proper

Comment: Some notes:  To get the selected value, use `$(this).val()`  You don't need to iterate over the options with the selected attribute, or look for the value attribute.  And...what's up with that `.change()` at the end of your functions?

Comment: Please edit your question to include how a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the problem (e.g. you say the Yes code works - however we cannot see that, to see what the difference is). i.e, please show us the generated HTML that the JD is working on, and not the template file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code structure is not proper otherwise it is working fine see below example

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#recurring").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
            if(optionValue=="No"){
                $("#Yes").hide()
            } else{
                $("#Yes").show();
            }
        })
});
  $("#before_after").change(function(){
      debugger
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue2 = $(this).attr("value");
            if(optionValue2=="Until the prayer after"){
                $("#Length-div").show();
            } else{
                $("#Length-div").hide();
            }
            
        })
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="required">
            <label class="control-label" for="before_after">When?</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="before_after" name="before_after" required="">
                <option selected="" value="Until the prayer after">Until the prayer after</option>
                <option value="Before">Before</option>
                <option value="After">After</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group  required">
            <label class="control-label" for="recurring">Recurring</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="recurring" name="recurring" required="">
                <option selected="" value="No">No</option>
                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div name="Length-div" id="Length-div" style="display:none;">
            {{ wtf.form_field(form.length)}}
        </div>

        <div name="Yes" id="Yes" style="display: none;">
            {{ wtf.form_field(form.frequency)}}
            {{ wtf.form_field(form.end)}}
        </div>
```

Comment: I have also removed your change() method because that was doing maximum call stack and that is really not needed if you want to do by default you can use css `style="display:none"`